# Performing loops with AWK, but using predefined variables

Tags: bash, awk

I'm trying to create a sequence of numbers in bash. I found that for very long sequences, using loops written into `awk` is much faster and time efficient than the conventional loop with `for; do; (sequence); done` For example, if I have 5 samples, and I want to create a time sequence starting from 0 s with an increment of 0.5 s between each sample, with `awk` I just write:

```
awk 'BEGIN {time=0; print time; for (i=1; i<5; ++i) {time += 0.5; print time}}'
```

And it works ... Now, I'm trying to use this command inside a script that automates the generation of several times sequences, where some of them have different number of points and different increments. So, I need to define previously some variables that are created based on the characteristics of each data set, and then use them inside `awk`. Something like this (applied to the previous example):

```
start=1
end=5
increment=0.5
awk 'BEGIN {time=0; print time; for (i=$start; i<$end; ++i) {time += $increment; print time}}'
```

But that does not work ... Obviously, it is a problem of syntax. I don't know the correct way to write this. I would appreciate a lot any suggestion.

Comment: `bash` variables and `awk` variables are different.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `-v` syntax to add the variables in `awk`, in the example below using the syntax I have imported the `bash` variables of the same name.

```
awk -v start="$start" -v end="$end" -v increment="$increment" 'BEGIN {time=0; print time; for (i=start; i<end; ++i) {time += increment; print time}}'
0
0.5
1
1.5
2
```

You can also directly adopt the variable values as

```
awk -v start=1 -v end=5 -v increment=0.5 'BEGIN {time=0; print time; for (i=start; i<end; ++i) {time += increment; print time}}'
0
0.5
1
1.5
2
```